# How can i get correct current timestamp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm currently enrolled in a freecodecamp backend certificate course and I'm asked to return a JSON response, in a chained middleware & handler, with the current time. the following is my code:

```
app.get("/now", (req,res,next)=>{
req.time = new Date().toString();
next();
}, 
(req,res)=>{
res.json({"time": req.time});
})
```

and  by matching th eroute "/now", I get this in my browser

```
{"time":"Sun Oct 14 2018 22:03:19 GMT+0000 (UTC)"}
```

So obviously I'm getting a correct JSON response but still the current time zone is GMT+1 not GMT+0. challenge can't be submitted correctly stating that "/now endpoint should return a time that is +/- 20 secs from now" which is correct.

Can any JS expert help with this matter.. would appreciate it enormously!!

Comment: @RobG - that is NodeJS - it is server code. My question is what timezone setting is getting in the way.

Comment: The timezone comes directly from the host system, so if it's not what you expect, check the host. Servers are generally set to UTC.

Comment: @RobG - right - the odd part is that this code is being executed/tested presumably on the same (freecodecamp) host. Then why the different UTC offsets?

Comment: I don't know, likely the code runs in an emulator or virtual environment so perhaps this is really a freecodecamp question?

Comment: Agreed. Can't groc the environment.

Comment: Is the time wrong though? "Sun Oct 14 2018 22:03:19 GMT+0000 (UTC)" is equivalent to "Sun Oct 14 2018 23:03:19 GMT+0100 (BST)". The bit that matters is "+0100", the bit in brackets is implementation dependent and ignoreable.

Comment: totally @RobG !! i need it to be 2018 23:03:19 GMT+0100!!!

Comment: @ChamsMansouri On server side to get timezone specific date you can use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your PC timezone is not the same as your browser. 
Check it out in this **[link](https://enddesign.medium.com/a-problem-you-might-have-while-doing-the-chain-middleware-to-create-a-time-server-challenge-from-44027ca483b9)**:

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587